# error exe-bad access after executing this line

Tags: iphone

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",[ConfigDB valueForKey:categoryURL], @"?ownerId=", 20,@"&userId=",64]];

can any one tell me wat wrong with this

Answer (score 4):

For numbers you are supposed to use %d, not %@.

```
@"%@%@%d%@%d"
```